# Extract only some part (duration) from a string

Tags: java

I used the following command to find the duration of an mp3 file:

$ ffmpeg -i audiofile.mp3 2>&1 | grep Duration

Duration: 01:02:20.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s

How can extract the Duration time (01:02:20.20) from the above result with Java code(method)?

Thanks in advance

Antonis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running this command through `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder` then you could just run:

```
ffmpeg -i audiofile.mp3 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

to get the duration straightaway, instead of doing parsing in Java.

Comment: Well i did that and it prints just nothing empty string?

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = Duration: 01:02:20.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s

int startIndex = str.indexOf(":");  
int endIndex = str.indexOf(",");

str.subString(startIndex,endIndex); //your result  
str.trim();
```

**Note: assumption is that the format will remain same**

Comment: I think you want `int startIndex = str.indexOf(" "); + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions would be a good place to start.

Comment: Don't you thinkg regular expressions are overkill for this?

Answer (score 2):

I *love* `String.split` :)

```
String duration = result.split("[ ,]")[1];
```

This splits on space or comma.

Comment: OP just wants the duration, "01:02:20.20", _without_ the string "Duration: ". I would also use String.split, though.

Comment: @Jaime - it works as expected on my machine: "Duration: " is not part of the result, it splits on the space *before* the duration value

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought you were splitting only on the comma.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the time in calculations, you'll need to parse the constituent parts.

```
String string = "Duration: 01:02:20.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s";

// This expects 3 millisecond digits, as specified by [ffmpeg docs]*, though
// sample only has 2... maybe it's variable - adjust as needed
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(?:\\.([0-9]{3}))?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

if (m.find()) {
    int h = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int m = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    int s = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
    int ms = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
    // do some time math
}
```

[ffmpeg docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5).